# Setup Breeze JS ajax adapter to send query string params instead headers

Tags: ajax, jquery, http-headers, query-string, breeze

Is it possible to setup Breeze JS ajax adapter to send additional query strings parameters? Now I am using custom headers params, but want to change our app to use query string params instead.

Current code:

```
    function configureAjaxAdapter() {
        var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
        ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("db", config.db);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("login", config.login);
            }
        }; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the EntityQuery.withParameters method.  This is the "preferred" (and safe) mechanism to pass query string params in a query.  For example:

```
var params = {
   db: config.db,
   login: config.login
};

var q = EntityQuery.from("Foos").withParameters(params);
myEntityManager.executeQuery(q).then(...)
```

Comment: this is great, but my biggest issue with this is that if you're passing secure info like username & password then they are transferred in plain text... Is there a way to pass an ad-hoc object to a breeze controller using POST

Comment: If you want you can post directly to the breeze controller via an ajax call without actually using breeze at all for this step. That said, we are working on something called an JsonRequestAdapter that will also do what you want. But ... this may not be released for several weeks yet.